# Strange behavior between rails and irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

If I drop in to irb and do `require 'atom'` I can successfully include the gem but if I try to include it in my controller in rails I get `no such file to load -- atom` when I visit the page in the browser. What's going on here?

Here's the complete stack trace:

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/Build/Contactly/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:3
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `load_file'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:379:in `load_file'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `require_or_load'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:425:in `load_missing_constant'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:361:in `constantize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:360:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:360:in `constantize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:162:in `constantize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:443:in `recognize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:436:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:50:in `service'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:111
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

irb is the interactive Ruby shell which is not rails. when you do gem install  you are making it available for your installed version of Ruby, however Rails is slightly different. Rails only interacts with the gems you have listed in your Gemfile. Assuming you are using Rails 3, you would edit your Gemfile to include to the gem

```
gem 'atom'
```

save the file and then run

```
bundle install
```

then, once you run `rails s` that gem is available to your rails application. For future note, if you want to try out how something will work in a rails context, instead of invoking `irb`, invoke `rails console` or `./script/rails console` (depending on which version of rails you are using).

Answer (score 0):

Did you include it in your gemfile?

Comment: no, I haven't had to do that with other gems...I just install the gem and go off to the races.

Comment: Try to include it into your gemfile.. Rails loads only the gems which are specified in the gemfile...